# How to access specific H2 database

Tags: jdbc, h2, squirrel-sql

I have 2 H2 databases under 2 different locations

```
D:\test\activitiDB\activiti.h2.db
and
D:\myapps\jbpmDB\jbpmdb1.h2.db
```

In Hsql, I can specify an alias name to the databases in Hsql properties files and simply use the alias name in the JDBC URL like so:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/myDB1
```

where the alias myDB1 actually points to some file location mentioned in the HSQL database.

Is it possible to use something similar in H2 database system?

So that I can access the H2 databases from a SQL client OR JAVA code by something like:

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/jbpmdb1
OR
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/activiti
```

Right now using the above URL shows this StackTrace in my SQL Client:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database "D:/apps/dumps/H2_DB/bin/activiti" not found [90013-172]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:54)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:160)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:139)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:122)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In H2, there is no alias mechanism as in HSQLDB. What you can do in H2 is set [one base directory](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Server.html?highlight=baseDir&search=baseDir#main_String...) per server. If you need multiple base directories, you could start multiple server (on different ports), as follows:

```
java org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -tcpPort 9091 -baseDir D:\test\activitiDB
java org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -tcpPort 9092 -baseDir D:\myapps\jbpmDB
```

Comment: To access the database from a client use a url that resembles this:

jdbc:h2:tcp://<serveraddress>:<port>/./<databasename>